# docker-compose can't find django-admin in $PATH, but I can run django-admin commands separately

Tags: python, django, docker

I'm trying to test a django app in a docker image. I have followed the [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/samples/django/) until the it starts the [django project](https://docs.docker.com/samples/django/#create-a-django-project). When I run, `docker-compose run web django-admin startproject composeexample .` I get

> Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
> container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec:
> "django-admin": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
> ERROR: 1

It's weird because I can run django-admin createproject ... seperately. Any thoughts?

I have added the ..\python39\scripts in the path. Also I have python 3.9.10 from the windows store.